# How to have a Project Reference without referencing the actual binary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-core-2.0, debug-symbols

Following works fine but it does not copy the .pdb file for Asp.net Core 2.0 project.

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj">
    <Project>{b402782f-de0a-41fa-b364-60612a786fb2}</Project>
    <Name>ProjectA</Name>
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <Targets>Build;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup</Targets>
</ProjectReference>
```

[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary/#comment-21266)

So, what should we do for copying the pdb file?

Comment: the "binary" usually means the dll; I assume you're really asking about copying the symbols file? I note from the article you link to that "Turns out there is a trick, but it doesn’t work when building in VS. But it’s OK since you don’t really need the .pdb in VS anyway," - how are you building? in VS? or at the command-line?

Comment: Ok sorry for inconvenience, i did not read that part exactly. I am building in VS and it works fine in VS, but i thought that pdb is required for some other reason, so for working at command-line etc.

Comment: So, if needed, it might be copied with a post-build event command line but i don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, what should we do for copying the pdb file?

Just as Marc and [that bolg](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary/#comment-21266) pointed out **this method not work in the Visual Studio** to copy the .pdb file. Because we set `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>`, the project reference without referencing the actual binary, VS/MSBuild will not copy the .pdb file.

> many people have asked how to also copy the .pdb file in addition to
>   the .exe/.dll. Turns out there is a trick, **but it doesn’t work when
>   building in VS**. But it’s OK since you don’t really need the .pdb in VS
>   anyway, since the debugger will find the .pdb at its original path
>   anyway.

If you still want to copy this .pdb file, you can use [MSBuild copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) or a [build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412.aspx) for your project:

**MSBuild copy task:**

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag , place below scripts:

```
<Target Name="CopyPDBfile" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)ProjectA\bin\Debug\ProjectA.pdb" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

**Build event:**

Add following build command line in the Pre-build/Post-build event:

```
xcopy /y "$(SolutionDir)ProjectA\bin\Debug\ProjectA.pdb" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Note: Do not ignore double quotes and spaces in the build command line.

Hope this helps.